# Show that there are an equal number of points on an infinite real line and an infinite real plane

Tags: real-analysis

If we can prove the following i reckon it satisfies the question asked but am unsure how to do it exactly.

$|\Bbb R| = |\Bbb R \times \Bbb R|$

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to do $|(0,1)| =|(0,1) \times (0,1)|$ and biject $(0,1)$ with $\Bbb R$.  Think about interleaving the binary expansions on the right bit by bit to get one on the left.  It takes a little cleaning up because of the ambiguity of binary expansions.